# Unclear code in C.. would be grateful if someone explain it to me

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

```
#ifndef HW4Q2_H_INCLUDED
#define HW4Q2_H_INCLUDED
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 10

struct dict{
    int len;
    char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
    char (*dict1)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
};

void translate(char* currWord, char* newWord, struct dict* myDict, int lang);
void createDict(struct dict* myDict);
void destroyDict(struct dict* myDict);

#endif
```

I have homework in c, and we have this header file.. but what does "char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];" means? I never saw this before.. is there any equivalent way to write it? plz explain me! i'm hopless :(
10q guys!

Comment: cdecl.org is a useful website for c declaration explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char (*dict0)[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
```

This code declares `dict0` to be a pointer to char arrays of size `MAX_WORD_LEN + 1`.

Also, if you don't have a C declaration parser such as `cdecl`, you can still use [this simple rule of thumb](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to understand complex types.

Comment: +1 For being correct. And for giving me proof that I can still decipher code correctly after a 12hr work day :)

Comment: @AlokSave Thanks. Yes, haters gonna hate, incorrect downvoters gonna incorrectly downvote :)

Comment: You could also add [Clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to your answer :)

Comment: @AlokSave I was aware of that, it's just that I didn't remember it's there :) Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my answer.

Comment: 10x!! And does it right to write it like that: char dict0[][MAX_WORD_LEN+1]; so we can say it functions like a matrix?

Comment: @user1980750 No, but why don't you try it? If you get a compiler error, then no.

Answer (score 3):

You should play around with [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/), it helps in parsing things like this.

If you substitute a number for the `MAX_WORD_LEN+1` expression (such as 11), it says:

> declare dict0 as pointer to array 11 of char

So that is what that code means; it declares `dict0` as a pointer to a `char` array with size `MAX_WORD_LEN + 1`, i.e. 11.

Comment: 10x for the answer and the site!